# How to extract summary data from mbir::swc_ind() in R?

Tags: r

I've just started using the `mbir` package in R and I'm wondering how I can extract the summary data that gets printed in the console (see below) when I run the `swc_ind()` function. I'd like to create a table/data frame with the data that is printed below *MBI From Trend Line:*, so I'm wondering if there's any way to do this. Thanks.

```
Trend Parameters:               
Slope     0.474
R-squared 0.283
F stat    2.973
P value   0.160

        Very Unlikely Very Unlikely Very Likely
        "Decrease"    "Trivial"     "Increase" 
MBI (%) "1"           "7"           "92"       

   MBI From Trend Line:

 Point   Diff    N  T  P                  MBI
     1   -1.3   88  7  5         Likely Lower
     2    0.6   26 12 62                  ---
     3    0.5   30 13 57                  ---
     4    0.9   21 11 68                  ---
     5    0.6   26 13 61                  ---
     6   -1.4   90  5  5    Very Likely Lower
```

Example from ***mbir*** page.

```
df <- c(97.5, 99.9, 100.2, 101.1, 101.3, 99.8)
mbir::swc_ind(x = df, swc = 0.25, ts = 0.2, type = "trend")
```

Answer (score 0):

That data is in a data.frame created by the function but not returned to caller. You can see it because it is printed with a `print` statement near the end of the function.

But R is open source and you can download the package source, edit the function, eventually giving it another name such as `swc_ind2` or any other of your choice, and rebuild the package. See [WRE](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html) on how to build R packages.

## 1. Source code

What I have done is to get the source code by running just the function name with parenthesis at an R prompt, save its source to file and edit the file.

```
mbir::swc_ind |> capture.output(file = "./mbir_swc_ind.R")
```

## 2. Edit the source

With a text editor I have changed the following:

```
# include  the function name and assignment 
#
# swc_ind <- 
#
# since it wasn't output
swc_ind <- function (x, swc, type = c("previous", "trend"), ts, te, main, 
    xlab, ylab)
```

and at the very end change

```
        names(noway) <- c("Point", " ", "Diff", " ", "N", "T", 
            "P", " ", "MBI")
        cat("\n   MBI From Trend Line:\n\n")
        print(noway, row.names = F)
        rval <- list(slope = table1[1], rsq = table1[2], fstat = table1[3], 
            p.value = table1[4])
    }
}
```

to

```
        names(noway) <- c("Point", " ", "Diff", " ", "N", "T", 
            "P", " ", "MBI")
        cat("\n   MBI From Trend Line:\n\n")
        print(noway, row.names = F)
    }
    if(type == "previous") {
        rval <- list(noway = noway)
    } else if(type == "trend") {
        rval <- list(slope = table1[1], rsq = table1[2], fstat = table1[3], 
            p.value = table1[4], noway = noway)
    }
    rval
}
```

## 3. Run the new code

Now run the function and see that it outputs the final data.frame.

```r
source("./mbir_swc_ind.R", local = .GlobalEnv)

df <- c(97.5, 99.9, 100.2, 101.1, 101.3, 99.8)

result <- swc_ind(x = df, swc = 0.25, ts = 0.2, type = "trend")
#>    Trend Parameters:               
#> Slope     0.474
#> R-squared 0.283
#> F stat    2.973
#> P value   0.160
#> 
#>         Very Unlikely Very Unlikely Very Likely
#>         "Decrease"    "Trivial"     "Increase" 
#> MBI (%) "1"           "7"           "92"
```

[image]

```
#> 
#>    MBI From Trend Line:
#> 
#>  Point   Diff    N  T  P                  MBI
#>      1   -1.3   88  7  5         Likely Lower
#>      2    0.6   26 12 62                  ---
#>      3    0.5   30 13 57                  ---
#>      4    0.9   21 11 68                  ---
#>      5    0.6   26 13 61                  ---
#>      6   -1.4   90  5  5    Very Likely Lower

result$noway
#>   Point   Diff    N  T  P                  MBI
#> 1     1   -1.3   88  7  5         Likely Lower
#> 2     2    0.6   26 12 62                  ---
#> 3     3    0.5   30 13 57                  ---
#> 4     4    0.9   21 11 68                  ---
#> 5     5    0.6   26 13 61                  ---
#> 6     6   -1.4   90  5  5    Very Likely Lower

result$noway |> class()
#> [1] "data.frame"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-04</sup>